# Recover Lost Dreamspark Windows 7 Key

Tags: windows-7, dreamspark

Is there anyway to recover a lost Windows 7 key obtained from Dreamspark (aka MSDNAA). I originally got the key from my university, but I am no longer a student so I do not have access to the website anymore.

All I have is a genuine copy of Windows 7 loaded with the Dreamspark key. I wish to reformat my disk, however I cannot install windows without the key.

I have tried several free software to retrieve the key from the registry. However, the key shows up as a generic key (all B's). From my understanding, this is because Dreamspark/MSDNAA keys are handled differently than other retail keys.

What are my options at this point?

Comment: Well.. technically you are not supposed to. Access to Dreamspark is only available when you are still a student. Yes you are allowed to still use the software even after you are no longer a student, but you can't really re-install by then as it means you are trying to access dreamspark resources (burnt installation DVD) even when you are no longer having access.

Comment: Enroll in some classes.

Comment: I wish I had written it down. Then I wouldn't have to go through so much trouble. From what I hear, the product key does not expire even if you are no longer a student.

Comment: You should write the key down in all cases. I discovered that when you first access the ket, you can never access it again even though you are still a student.